# How to check out (get) a specific version/revision of source using Team Explorer Everywhere CLC

Tags: version-control, tfs, revision, team-explorer-everywhere

I need to be able to check out a specific version of the source from TFS using Team Explorer Everywhere command line client.

```
$ tf workspace -new MyWS -collection:http://example.com/tfs/DefaultCollection
....
$ mkdir myws
$ tf workfold -map -workspace:MyWS $/Project $(pwd)/myws
...
$ cd myws
$ tf get
...
```

The above sequence of commands will fetch/check out the latest version from TFS.
How do I force TEE command line client to check out/get me a specific version of the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **tf get** command takes a "**-version:**" option where the changeset number can be specified:

```
$ tf get -version:12345
```

For more information, see:

```
$ tf help get
```

The help text does not specify the format of the "**-version:**" value, but plain numbers work for me in order to specify changesets.

Comment: There is documentation - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx , notably the discussion of the "version spec".  (A bare number indicates the changeset number, as you note.)